# Casting a JavaCC grammar definition into VSCode syntax highlight?

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, vespa, language-extension

I'm using the Yahoo's [Vespa](http://vespa.ai/) engine that involves a specific grammar in its configurations files (called `SearchDefinition`). I have access to the grammar of that configuration language through a JavaCC `.jj` file (see [my issue](https://github.com/vespa-engine/vespa/issues/10531) on Vespa's Github).
My goal is to use that grammar to build a syntax-highlighting extension for VSCode according to [VSC's documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#developing-a-new-grammar-extension).

Problem: VSC's tool used to build a new syntax-highlighting needs a TextMate-like grammar and not a JavaCC-like grammar. My question is : how to convert a JavaCC grammar into a TextMate grammar ?

Thanks :)